# Asyncpraw basic reddit API example throws error right after execution

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, praw, asyncpraw

I just got into trying to make a bot using the AsyncPraw Reddit API wrapper. I copy-pasted the [code example in the documentation](https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/quick_start.html) and i can't get it to run without getting atleast a warning.

by trying to execute this code:

```
import asyncpraw
import asyncio
import auth
from time import sleep
async def amain():
    reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(
        client_id=auth.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=auth.CLIENT_SECRET,
        user_agent="Example bot",
        password=auth.PASSWORD,
        username=auth.USERNAME,
        ratelimit_seconds=700
    )

    print(reddit.read_only)
    # Output: True
    # continued from code above

    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("askreddit")
    async for submission in subreddit.top(limit=10):
        print(submission.title)


asyncio.run(amain())
```

Everything works, the submission titles get printed, but then, this happens:

```
> Unclosed client session client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession
> object at 0x000001D53CA8D6C0> Unclosed connector connections:
> ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at
> 0x000001D53C246FE0>, 116575.906)]'] connector:
> <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x000001D53CA8D7E0> Fatal
> error on SSL transport protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object
> at 0x000001D53CA8EB30> transport: <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=-1
> read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>
```

> ...

```
> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

tried to fix by replacing the `asyncio.run(amain())` with:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(amain())
```

and this fixes the `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`, but the `Unclosed client session client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession`. and all the things that follow it remain.

and on top of that, now i get a

> DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

Answer (score 0):

Found answer by myself. i just need to add
`asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())`

before

`asyncio.run(amain())`

and it will work without errors or warnings.